# What were the most common software distribution formats for MacOS Classic?

Tags: apple-macintosh, file-format, mac-os-classic

What were the most common formats for distributing applications for System 6/7-era MacOS Classic? Were applications distributed on floppies/CDs or online/via FTP/via BBSs? And what format were applications most commonly distributed in (eg. dmg, img, sit, bin).

Bonus question: were there any package managers during this timeframe (an app store or something like [homebrew](https://brew.sh) or any central package repositories?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Up until things like Compuserve and AOL (and then Internet for the masses) came around, floppy disks would have more or less been the only option.

(CD-ROM drives in consumer machines arrived only a few years before the Internet burst onto the scene and, for the purposes of answering your question, they weren't appreciably different from floppy disks.)

As for digital distribution, these were the factors at play:

- Classic Mac OS was designed from the ground up to be serviced without special install/remove tools.

  - The equivalent to `SYS C: A:` is "Click and drag a System folder onto the device you want to be bootable".
  - An application that doesn't integrate with the system when not running (aside from file associations) requires no special installation. Just the mac equivalent of "unzip and run".
  - Things like system extensions just need to be dropped into the System Folder (System 6) or the correct subfolder (System 7).
  - To the greatest extent reasonably possible, Macintosh system extensions are single self-contained files. (eg. a Control Panel can also embed an Extension so that it's one file to be dragged into the trash to uninstall.)
  - I can't remember if it was added in System 7.0, 7.1, or 7.5, but the system would pop up a dialog offering to put files into the correct subfolders if you dragged and dropped them onto the System Folder.
- System 7 and below predate public Internet, so there was generally no expectation of applications receiving updates.

  - Up until Apple realized they could make good money selling System 7.1, the common way to get a System update was to visit your local computer store with some blank floppies (or buy a box from them) and just copy whatever was running on the newest demo machine.
- Macintosh files have a data fork (the "bag of bytes" that other OSes have) and a resource fork (a key-value store loosely akin to POSIX Extended Attributes or NTFS Alternate Streams) and 68k Macintosh applications store their executable code in the resource fork, which means that Macintosh files need to be packed up in a form that will preserve the resource fork before being stored on a non-Apple filesystem or sent over a wire.
- The `.dmg` variant of Apple Disk Images wasn't invented until Mac OS X

...so the common ways to offer Mac stuff for download during the period when classic Mac OS overlapped with commodity networking were:

- StuffIt `.sit` archives (StuffIt served the role PKZip did for DOS, and gained popularity through a similar approach to licensing. Competitors analogous to ARC, ARJ, LHA, and ZOO included CompactPro, DiskDoubler, and PackIt.)
- Self-extracting archives (eg. StuffIt `.sea`) and Self-mounting Disk Images (`.smi`) wrapped up in a format like BinHex (`.hqx`) or MacBinary (`.bin`) which was a single-file wrapper akin to `.gz` or `.bz2` but, instead of adding compression, they folded the resource fork down into the data fork for transport.
- Apple Disk Copy 4.2 images (`.img`) inside BinHex or MacBinary, because they store metadata in the resource fork.
- For applications that had a complex installation process (eg. CodeWarrior IDE) or wanted a one-click way to install dependencies like newer versions of QuickTime, Game Sprockets (Apple's DirectX analogue that came out during the tail end of the Mac OS 7 era), etc., there *did* exist installer wizards, which would be packed up in one of the above mentioned forms, similar to how pre-PackageForTheWeb InstallShield would often be inside a WinZip Self-Extractor `.exe` or similar:

  - Apple's Macintosh Programmer's Workshop included a copy of the Installer framework Apple used, similar to how the Windows 3.1 SDK included a copy of MS Setup 1.x. I haven't personally run across many third-party applications using it.
  - Installer VISE was, for the most part, the InstallShield of classic Mac OS (though, as I mentioned, installer wizards were a minority). This was most likely because freeware and shareware authors could [apply for a free license for Installer VISE Lite](https://web.archive.org/web/19961115030804/http://www.mindvision.com/web2/Products/IVISELite/Installer_VISE_Lite_Index.html#SHAREWARE).
  - Later on, Aladdin Software released StuffIt InstallerMaker. I get the impression it started to become what commercial vendors preferred around the tail end of the lifespan of classic Mac OS, but that's just anecdotal. (Partly from vague memories of seeing some products switch from Installer VISE to InstallerMaker and wondering why.)

Answer (score 13):

The "System 6/7-era" extends from 1988 to at least 1997 — 10 years that saw a a lot of changes in the IT industry[1].

From personal experience, Software distribution was mostly on physical media for most of that time, starting with floppy disks, and changing to CD-ROMS somewhere around 1993, first as an option for larger pieces of software, then becoming the default around 1995.

Online distribution was limited by bandwidth (9600 baud was fast for a modem in the late 80s), availability (Internet access was initially rare outside universities and tech companies; and BBSes were more of a geekish hobby than a mainstream software distribution channel) and cost (long-distance calls were *expensive*, and depending on where you were in the world, even local calls would be metered). Some of that changed with the rise of the World Wide Web and large-scale Internet Service Providers in the mid-90s, but even at 56K, you'd rarely download anything larger than a couple of megabytes - think patches and utilities rather than major applications.

I can't recall package management for MacOS (or, in fact, MS Windows); that was more of a Unix / Linux thing. For package management to make sense, you need a centralised publisher (which in turn means open source, cross licensing, or an app-store-sort-of-thing), and you'd benefit greatly from internet access. The former wasn't a thing at the time -- everyone packaged and distributed their own software -- and the latter wasn't generally available.

[1] From your question, I gather that you were not around at the time?

Comment: Yes... born a few years later :)

Answer (score 10):

In terms of formats for BBS/online distribution, [StuffIt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StuffIt) and [MacBinary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBinary) were common for binary transfers.  [BinHex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BinHex) was common for 7-bit text-based transfers. All three preserved the data fork, resource fork, and Finder info (file type / creator type).

Disk Images were usually in [Disk Copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_Copy) (4.2) format.  Wrapping a 50k file in a 1600k disk image is pretty wasteful for a 2400 baud modem so that was usually only used when a disk image was actually needed.

MacBinary is fairly simple wrapper and doesn't involve any compression.  Any decent terminal programs could automatically encode files while uploading and decode when downloading.

StuffIt archives were sometimes distributed as self extracting archives (sea) so they could be run to extract themselves, without needing StuffIt.  Since a macintosh application requires a resource fork and Finder info, they would commonly be wrapped in MacBinary as well when uploading to a BBS or (later) the internet.